# JAVA: how to convert an array formatted String to String array

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have a string object that looks like this: [dog,cat,bird,panda]. It's in array format but its not an actual array object.  How do i convert this quickly to a String array object that looks exactly the same?

Comment: Remove the brackets then split on comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String str = "[dog,cat,bird,panda]";
String[] arr = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");
```

Comment: Note, this will work for the current string, but will NOT work if any of the substrings (values) have brackets in them.

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "[dog,cat,bird,panda]";
String subdata = data.substring(1, data.length() - 1 );
String[] parts = subdata.split(",");
```

That should do it.

Comment: I think you meant `length() - 1`.

Comment: @Andreas I'm trying to strip off that last bracket, so length() - 2 seems right.

Comment: Your code causes `subdata` to be `"dog,cat,bird,pand"`, because you're truncating the last `a` too.

Comment: Yup, seems you're right... forgot endIndex was exclusive... changing